# How to correctly use "perspective"?

Tags: phrases, expressions, semantics

> I plan to explore this question from various statistical perspectives, including Bayesian theory and probability measurement."

Is this sentence right? Bayesian theory and probability measurement are all sub-fields of statistics. Can they be considered as "perspectives"?

Comment: It all depends on how you look at it.

Comment: @Hot Licks Words almost fail me.

Comment: A 'perspective' in this sense is a 'point of view'. Strictly, you require "I plan to explore this question from various statistical perspectives, including those provided by Bayesian theory and probability measurement."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely, as per the [definition](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/perspective)

> The interrelation in which a subject or its parts are mentally viewed
>       places the issues in proper perspective

More simply, this use of perspective is valid insofar as it refers to any topic which could provide a framework for thought. Bayesian theory undoubtedly fits that mold.